# How to disable autocomplete in asp:login control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete

Is there a way of using `autocomplete="off"` in `<asp:Login> </asp:login>`. I tried to convert  asp:login to template and put the autocomplete="off" attribute in asp:TextBox element however this breaks other part of login process. Is there a way of disabling autocomplete without using javascript and without converting to template. if its possible behind code is fine. Look forward to your suggestions. Thanks

Here is the code in Page_Load

```
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var control = this.FindControlRecursive(LoginArea, "UserName") as TextBox;

        if (control != null)
        {
            control.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
        }

        var control2 = this.FindControlRecursive(LoginArea, "Password") as TextBox;

        if (control2 != null)
        {
            control2.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
        }
    }
```

And here aspx page:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginArea" runat="server" SkinID="Login" CssSelectorClass="PrettyLogin"
                   DestinationPageUrl="Home.aspx" LoginButtonImageUrl="" 
                   LoginButtonText="login button"
                   LoginButtonType="Button" 
                   UserNameLabelText="username>" 
                   PasswordLabelText="password"
                   TitleText="title" 
                   RememberMeSet="false" DisplayRememberMe="false" 
                   FailureText="failed"
                   ToolTip="tool tip"
                   PasswordRecoveryText="" 
                   PasswordRecoveryUrl="urlforpasswordrecovery"
                   CreateUserText="" 
                   CreateUserUrl="" OnLoggedIn="LogOn_LoggedIn"
                   OnLoggingIn="LogOn_LoggingIn" OnLoginError="LogOn_Error" >
        </asp:Login>
```

Answer (score 11):

To turn off auto-complete for your entire form, all you need to do is add an attribute to your form tag, like this:

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
```

Easy enough. Now you won't get the auto complete on any of the controls on the form, works for any browser that supports auto-complete. The HTML INPUT tags also support the use of autocomplete=off and since the control renders as INPUT tags then you can use it to set it on a control by control basis. Just add it to the TextBox at design-time (but note that VS.NET will underline it with a squiggly saying that textbox does not have an attribute for autocomplete - but it will still work):

```
<asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="Textbox1" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

or at runtime:

```
Textbox1.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
```

Comment: autocomplete="off" in textbox is working for me in Firefox 40.0.3

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

.aspx

```
<asp:Login runat="server" ID="login"></asp:Login>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var control = FindControlRecursive(login, "Password") as TextBox;

        control.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
    }
}
```

```
public Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    Control first = null;
    foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
    {
     Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
     if (t != null)
     {
        first = t;
        break;
      }
   }
   return root.ID == id ? root : first;
}
```

This is example for Password field. For user name use "UserName" instead of "Password" for the second parameter of `FindControlRecursive` method.

Comment: nope. I was hoping this would work but when I view the source I cannot see the autocomplete="off" in the input tag unfortunately.

Comment: Hm.. thats odd. I tried the sample code my self and it's working. This is the html that i get.
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$login$Password" type="password" id="MainContent_login_Password" autocomplete="off" />.

You must be missing some detail. Can you paste your code?

Comment: is the "login" in your code is the id of the login control? I just copied and paste your code and added a control for Username as well. but I use securityPanel in aspx pages would do anything ?

Comment: yes "login" is the id of login control. I think that securityPanel is not causing problems.
Paste your .aspx in .aspx.cs so that I can see your code and easily figure out what wrong on your side.

Comment: I revised and put the code. Could you please have a look? Thanks

Comment: FindControlRecursive method is the same as yours inside login.asp.cs

Comment: I tried your code in a sample asp.net web forms project (.NET 2.0, .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5) and the code is working in all versions.
Did you try to debug your code, to see if Page_Load event if fired and that FindControlRecursive returns right control?

Comment: yes I did debug it and I can see that FindControlRecursive returns the right control.What else I figured out is that it works when I convert the login to template. it adds the attributes but when I reset it back it doesnt work. maybe your login control is converted to template?

Comment: I didn't convert it to template. It must work, please double check the html output.

Comment: No mate it is not there. I even search it on the page and tehre is no autocomplete at all. When I convert it to template it gets there. I only can see the parameter accesskey="p" for password and accesskey="u" parameter for username :(

Comment: Then try to remove if (!Page.IsPostBack) from Page_Load to inject the attributes on every request. I suspect that login control isn't visible the first time page is loaded..

Answer (score 2):

**Follow the following steps**

1. Open Login Web Page in design mode
2. Select Login Control and click on > and select Convert to Template (if username and password textbox is not visible).
3. Select Login Textbox an Press F4 to show property window and set AutoCompleteType="Disabled" Similarly for Password. See the attached image.[image]

Comment: Im coming late to the party, but this is the correct answer that should be accepted.

Without the designer its just a matter to add `AutoCompleteType="Disabled"` inside the desired tag